# jQuery input filter for textarea

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, filter, keyup

I adapted [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2812649/338840) into my script. The idea is to prevent the user from typing unauthorized characters (of course there is also a filter on the back end).

```
$('#someinput').keyup(function() {
    var $th = $(this);
    $th.val( $th.val().replace(/[^a-zA-Z0-9]/g, function(str) {
        console.log(str);
        return '';
    }))
})
```

It works nice, but I also need the users to be able to type specific allowed characters like: .,!?ñáéíóú - I mean, the basic a-zA-Z0-9 plus some basic chars and the whole bunch of special language characters.

What actually needs to be left out are: @#$%^&*()=_+"':;/<>\|{}[]

Any ideas? Thanks!

**Solution** thanks to [Michael](https://stackoverflow.com/users/541091/michael)

```
//query
$('#someinput').keyup(function() {
    var $th = $(this);
    $th.val($th.val().replace(/[@#$%\^&*()=_+"':;\/<>\\\|{}\[\]]/g,function(str){return '';}));
}).bind('paste',function(e) {
    setTimeout(function() {
        $('#someinput').val($('#someinput').val().replace(/[@#$%\^&*()=_+"':;\/<>\\\|{}\[\]]/g,function(str){return '';}));
        $('#someinput').val($('#someinput').val().replace(/\s+/g,' '));
    },100);
});
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6565480/javascript-jquery-regex-replace-input-field-with-valid-characters see if this helps

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Invert your regular expression to only replace the specific characters you want omitted:

```
$th.val( $th.val().replace(/\s?[@#$%\^&*()=_+"':;\/<>\\\|{}\[\]]/g, ""));
// Edit: added optional \s to replace spaces after special chars
```

Note, a few of them need to be escaped with a backslash inside a `[]` character class: `\\\[\]\^\/`

Comment: great! i also added this to the bind('paste'),function(e) to run the regex when the user pastes a bunch of text. if he pastes: "hello @ friend" the result will be "hello  friend" that is ok excepto that there are 2 spaces instead of one. is it possible to prevent more than one space in the same regex? or should i place it in a separate regex for the bind() event only.

Comment: @andufo you can put an optional space before & after the `[]` above. Try my edit above and see if it works for you. Otherwise, you can just do another replacement to collapse multiple spaces: `/\s+/` replace with one space.

Comment: I think I would probably just do a second replacement myself, rather than try to modify that regex

Answer (score 3):

If I'm understanding what you are wanting to do, can't you just add those unwanted characters to your regex instead of doing the `[^a-zA-Z0-9]`?

Replace that with `[@#\$%\^&\*\(\)=_\+"':;\/<>\\\|\{\}\[\]]` (notice the escaping)