# replace "umlaute" like ÄÖÜ while typing

Tags: jquery, replace

i'm new at jquery scripting and hope you can help me.
google can't :(

i am trying to get a jquery script working, that replace some "umlaute" i.e. "Ä", "Ö", ...
while the user is typing in a textbox.

if a user write for example an Ä, than it should automatically replaced with a AE.

thank you in advance,
best regards

**--
edit:**

the script, that i have trouble with, is the script below.
it works for one letter (without if and else), but not when i want to run this with multiple replacement...

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#uml").keyup(function(){
    $(this).val(function(i, v) { //index, current value
      if(v=="ä") { return "ae"; }
      if(v=="ö") { return "oe"; }
      else
       {
        return v;
       }
}); });
});
```

thanks in advance!

Comment: Those are distinct characters, so [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6565480/901048) should point you in the right direction.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See [the documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) for JS string `replace` method.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#uml").keyup(function() {
        var text = $(this).val();
        $(this).val(
            text.replace("ä", "ae")
                .replace("ö", "oe")
                .replace("ü", "ue")
        );
    });
});
```

Note this usage of `replace` only replaces a single instance of the target string, which should be fine since you run this on `keyup`. If you need to replace every instance, however, you would use it like this:

```
text = text.replace(/ä/g,"ae");
```

Answer (score -2):

```
$(document).ready(function($){
  $("#textFieldID").keyup(function(){
    var newVal = $(this).val();
    val.replace("emlaute","ÄÖÜ");
    $(this).val(newVal);
  });
});
```